# How can I display iterm2 colors on Mac OS sierra?

Tags: macos, iterm2

I keep changing the iterm2 profiles and colors in the preferences. They are not working as I don't see any changes. I also added these to my .profile.

```
# Set CLICOLOR if you want Ansi Colors in iTerm2
export CLICOLOR=1

# Set colors to match iTerm2 Terminal Colors
export TERM=xterm-256color
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

Thanks for the help.